# Как подключиться к БД с помощью Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Что и как надо делать, чтобы подключиться к ORACLE БД с помощью Java?

Среда Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачать драйвера oracle. (ojdbcXX.jar - если обычное  подключение, или  установить клиента что бы подключиться к oracle cluster)
2. Либо  в переменной  CLASSPATH указать где расположены  скаченные  драйвера, либо в проекте указать на драйвера.
3. Сконфигурировать параметры подключения к Oracle
4. Использовать обьект Connection для  получения  физического подключения  к Oracle
5. Выполнить sql statement
6. Обработать  resultset